# Duplicate resource on deadlock xml

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

As I was debugging a deadlock, I noticed that in the xml's `resource-list`, the first and third object locks are the same. Is there some reason for this?

The `<resource-list>` verbatim:

```
 <resource-list>
  <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="580509447" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="censoredV2.dbo.pt_sales" id="lock1929b2d5500" mode="Sch-M" associatedObjectId="580509447">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process194df0e5468" mode="Sch-M" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process1947a066ca8" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </objectlock>
  <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="94623380" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="censoredV2.dbo.pt" id="lock1929a8cf480" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="94623380">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process1907da684e8" mode="IX" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process194df0e5468" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </objectlock>
  <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="580509447" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="censoredV2.dbo.pt_sales" id="lock1929b2d5500" mode="Sch-M" associatedObjectId="580509447">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process1947a066ca8" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process1907da684e8" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </objectlock>
 </resource-list>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not the same. If you look at it more closely the "owner id" is different.
This is 'Schema Modification' lock. SQL Server only allows one schema modification lock.

On the first one it is owned by `process194df0e5468` and it is granted.
On the third one, it is requested by `process1947a066ca8` and waiting, since the first one already has the lock.

This is [nice reading](https://michaeljswart.com/2013/04/the-sch-m-lock-is-evil/) about this lock by Michael J.Swart.